# Angularjs http post Multiple response

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post, httpwebresponse

I'm using angularjs and asp.net mvc as backend. Im returning the file to client side i set `responseType: "arraybuffer"` in $http.post it work perfectly. Now along with that file i need to response with the some data or collection. How this can be achieved?